# C++ Not Counting white beands

Tags: c++, arrays, string, counter

I need some help. I'm writing a code in `C++` that will ultimately take a random string passed in, and it will do a break at every point in the string, and it will count the number of colors to the right and left of the break (r, b, and w). Here's the catch, the `w` can be either `r` or `b` when it breaks or when the strong passes it ultimately making it a hybrid. My problem is when the break is implemented and there is a `w` immediately to the left or right I can't get the program to go find the fist `b` or `r`. Can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "P2Library.h"

void doubleNecklace(char neck[], char doubleNeck[], int size);
int findMaxBeads(char neck2[], int size);
#define SIZE 7

void main(void)
{
    char necklace[SIZE];
    char necklace2[2 * SIZE];
    int brk;
    int maxBeads;
    int leftI, rightI, leftCount = 0, rightCount=0, totalCount, maxCount = 0;
    char leftColor, rightColor;
    initNecklace(necklace, SIZE);

    doubleNecklace(necklace, necklace2, SIZE);
    maxBeads = findMaxBeads(necklace2, SIZE * 2);
    checkAnswer(necklace, SIZE, maxBeads);

    printf("The max number of beads is %d\n", maxBeads);
}

int findMaxBeads(char neck2[], int size)
{
    int brk;
    int maxBeads;
    int leftI, rightI, leftCount = 0, rightCount=0, totalCount, maxCount = 0;
    char leftColor, rightColor;

    for(brk = 0; brk < 2 * SIZE - 1; brk++)
    {
        leftCount = rightCount = 0;
        rightI = brk;
        rightColor = neck2[rightI];

        if(rightI == 'w')
        {
            while(rightI == 'w')
            {
                rightI++;
            }
            rightColor = neck2[rightI];
        }
        rightI = brk;

        while(neck2[rightI] == rightColor || neck2[rightI] == 'w')
        {
            rightCount++;
            rightI++;
        }

        if(brk > 0)
        {
            leftI = brk - 1;
            leftColor = neck2[leftI];

            if(leftI == 'w')
            {
                while(leftI == 'w')
                {
                    leftI--;
                }
                leftColor = neck2[leftI];
            }
            leftI = brk - 1;

            while(leftI >= 0 && neck2[leftI] == leftColor || neck2[leftI] == 'w')
            {
                leftCount++;
                leftI--;
            }
        }
        totalCount = leftCount + rightCount;
        if(totalCount > maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = totalCount;
        }
    }
    return maxCount;
}

void doubleNecklace(char neck[], char doubleNeck[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        doubleNeck[i] = neck[i];
        doubleNeck[i+size] = neck[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered putting some actual *data* in the `necklace[]` array prior to relying on its content for comparisons when passed to your function? I.e. where is `initNecklace()`?

Comment: It calls a separate file for a random string into the data that gives it the data. So every time I run the program I can see whether it's right or not.

Comment: That being the case, since your buffers are only 7 and 14 chars long *each*, have you (a) used one or more known-static initial 7-char necklace that exhibit the same problem, and (b) stepped through with a **debugger** to see where things appear to fall apart?

Comment: Yes to both. The problem is with counting to the left of the break. Everything to the right seems to be working fine, but I cannot firugre out in my code what is different about the left that would make it not work correctly.

Comment: Any chance you could include one of those static strings in your test above? It would make it *much* easier to walk the code, even on paper, if we know what these things look like. Thanks.

Comment: cullen how can you check rightI == 'w' in findmaxbeads? it should be rightcolor and not rightI isnt it? rightI is used for indexing

Comment: can you give a sample string for to dry run the code with that string?

Comment: Here is an example: necklace[SIZE] = {'r', 'b', 'w', 'w', 'w', 'b', 'r'};

Comment: In response to @Koushik, that is correct, I fixed that. Program still broken.

Comment: in your findmaxbeads() when it hits the while loop with rightcolor = 'w' it ends up in a infinite loop for the 3rd iteration of the for loop. fix that part of the while loop and repost the code if it still is broken

Answer (score 0):

I didn't study the code in detail, but something is not symmetric: in the `for` loop, the "left" code has an `if` but the "right" code doesn't. Maybe you should remove that `-1` in the `for` condition and add it as an `if` for the "right" code:

```
for(brk = 0; brk < 2 * SIZE; brk++)
{
    leftCount = rightCount = 0;

    if (brk < 2 * SIZE - 1)
    {
        rightI = brk;
        rightColor = neck2[rightI];

        //...
    }

    if(brk > 0)
    {
        leftI = brk - 1;
        leftColor = neck2[leftI];

        //...
    }

    //...
```

Just guessing, though... :-/

Maybe you should even change those `<` for `<=`.